# Angular 7 HTTP Interceptor is not working

Tags: angular7, angular-http-interceptors

I am new to Angular and I am trying to implement api call which send token in header on all api so I am using Interceptor.

I am not able to set header in request.

jwt.interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor() { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        let currentUser = localStorage.getItem('useremail')
        let currentUserToken = localStorage.getItem('token')
        if (currentUser && currentUserToken) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    'Authorization': `${currentUserToken}`
                }
            });
        }
        // console.log("Request", request)
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppUserListingComponent } from './app-user-listing/app-user-listing.component';
import { JwtInterceptor } from './jwt.interceptor';

@NgModule({
  providers: [ { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true } ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

user-listing.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserListingService {
  apiUrl = "URL";
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  fetchAllUsers() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/fetchAdminsUsers`)
  }

}
```

What is the reason my code is not working ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try use `'Authorization': currentUserToken`

Comment: I have tried using static as well but not working..

Comment: Do the api request work?? `apiUrl = "URL";`??

Comment: Yes there is my API url which perfectly working..

Comment: `if (currentUser && currentUserToken)` is it true?(maybe this `false`)

Comment: It works for me perfect:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-interceptors-uudcc8?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: see image:https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePPLp.png

Comment: I have tested it without condition but still no luck

Comment: do you check the `Authorization` in the F12 network as in my image?

Comment: see this https://imgur.com/aK5IuMD

Comment: copy this error and google search about solution

Comment: I know CORS and I am aware about this.. request : https://imgur.com/SKrg2hL
response : https://imgur.com/3GjHH25

Comment: so there is no connection to the `Authorization`

Comment: and GET method becomes OPTIONS. what about that ?

Comment: check above screenshots of my both headers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your app.module.ts code there's no `import: [HttpClientModule]` Do you have imported the `HttpClientModule`?

I'm experiencing a similar issue with angular 8.x http interceptor is not working OK.

Comment: Now I have updated Angular with 8 and now it is working

Answer (score 2):

Add `imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule]` in **@NgModule**.

Answer (score 1):

`Authorization` is a special header, you need to add `withCredentials: true` to the request to add it.

```
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'Authorization': `${currentUserToken}`
            },
            withCredentials: true
        });
```

Comment: No? `withCredentials` means send cookies; it has no impact on headers. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Answer (score 0):

try using instance of like below.

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
            tap(
                event => {
                    if(event instanceof HttpResponse){
                        //api call success
                         console.log('success in calling API : ', event);
                    }
                },
                error => {
                    if(event instanceof HttpResponse){
                        //api call error
                        console.log('error in calling API : ', event);
                    }
                }
            )
        )
```

Comment: also while calling api use httpClient :
return this.httpClient.post<any>('url',{options});

Comment: When i use above script is showing "Can not find name tap"